# Open basic Html date control on button click

Tags: javascript, html, angular, date, click

I want to  open html date control (input with type='date') on click of button.

Currently it is opening only on click of calendar icon which browser adds.

Reference -
https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-a-basic-angular-component-xtzkpp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Does this work? document.getElementById('date').focus();

Comment: Thanks @RinkeshGolwal  for the reply this will just focus will not open the calender

Comment: Any other idea/ trick you think.

Comment: May be better to use components like bootstrap.

Comment: Yes, Thanks  planning the same now.